# How to run a batch file after Microsoft Office 2016 has closed

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, backup, batch, microsoft-office-2016

Years ago, when I was running Outlook 2003, I had an add-in from CodePlex called `OutlookBackupAddIn` that would execute a batch file whenever Office 2003 closed, allowing the most current .PST file to be backed up to a different location.

Years after, we upgraded to Office 2016, and the functionality quit working, but for some reason, it still opened the *directory* where the batch file was contained, so I could trigger the batch manually.  All was still good.

But now, I've noticed that the functionality that was opening the directory isn't anymore, and as such, my daily backups simply aren't happening, which prompts me to search again for a better solution.

Is there anywhere in the Microsoft Office 2016 settings something that would specify a batch file or even a file folder to open after Office is shut down?  Then, I could tell it to run my backup batch, and all will be well in the world again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any option within Office itself but you could start Outlook by running a script instead of using the normal shortcut. Here is an example:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16
outlook.exe
start C:\folder\script.bat
```

This will first open Outlook and run the script.bat once Outlook has been closed.
You will however see an Command Line window all the time while running Outlook (and you must not close this window in order for the script to work). There are however ways to make batch files run invisible if this bothers you. And you could of course also create a shortcut to the script and give it the Outlook icon to make it look better.

Comment: I totally forgot about wrapping Outlook in a batch -- thanks for this idea!

Answer (score 0):

Here is our final result:
One batch file with:

```
start /min "Outlook" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OutlookWithBackup.bat"
```

This causes the cmd window to be minimized.

The second with:

```
@echo off

tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq outlook.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "outlook.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto Quit

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\outlook.exe
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodePlex\outlookbackupaddin\BackupOutlookWithoutRebooting.bat"

:Quit
```

This tests to ensure that Outlook isn't already running, and if it does, it quits.  If it isn't running, it starts it, then runs our backup process when it's finished.